# Locale in route prefix

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I'm trying to prefix all routes within single controller with `_locale` but so far I haven't had any success:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/events", requirements={"_locale": "en"})
 * @Route("/{_locale}/evenements", requirements={"_locale": "fr"})
 */
class SomeController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="events")
     */
    public function indexAction(){
       ... 
    }

    ...
}
```

`route:debug` does not even list URLs prefixed by second `@Route`. I tried removing `_locale` slug altogether but still, route could not be found.

Am I missing something here? Is it even possible to have multiple prefixes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Why won't you use [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle)?

Comment: Yes, I was (currently it's disabled) but then I realized that it did not support slug translation - not this particular case. Maybe it was too much to ask? :) I needed the `requirement`s of route translated as well...

Comment: @jperovic There was a [similar issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7724) recently posted. You might try downgrading Symfony to 2.1. Alternatively you could try defining multiple routes in a separate configuration file - worth a shot.

Comment: @Crozin: I'd really like to thank you! :) Because of your comment I decided to stick with `JMSI18n` and figured that I was not running "route extraction" (explanation located within `usage.rst` file). After doing so, translating routes and placing the output file in my bundle everything started working just the way I wanted :)

@gilden I see that issue is dagerously fresh, I didn't experience it during the development. :-/ (Maybe because I didn't use `requirement` with single choice, but thanks for point it out...

Comment: I'm very tired now, but I will do my best to answer my own question tomorrow with complete procedure of what I did here :)

Comment: @Crozin Can you please submit an "official" answer? :) I would like to close this question and assign points to your answer ;)

Comment: But it's you, who answered the question, and I believe you're the one who will write it in the most comprehensive manner. There's absolutely nothing wrong with acception own answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you have defined in your file Ressources/config/routing.yml that you're using annotation for this controller ?

```
#file Ressources/config/routing.yml
blog:
    resource: "@YourBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
```

Also you can define your routes as :

```
/**
 * @Route("/en/events", defaults={"_locale": "en"})
 * @Route("/fr/evenements", defaults={"_locale": "fr"})
 */
```

Comment: I was on a project using this "manual" solution, and after tried  JMSI18nRoutingBundle, and yes, this bundle is a good and simple solution I recommend.