# Symfony 2 placeholder in route prefix

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm declaring routes like this :

**config.yml**

```
vw_front:
    resource: "@VWFrontBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    defaults: { _locale: "%locale%" }
    requirements:
        _locale: "%locales%"
```

**@VWFrontBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**

```
vw_front_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: "VWFrontBundle:FrontIndex:index" }
```

Unfortunatelly, when i go to `app_dev.php` i get:

```
No route found for "GET /"
```

It is working with `app_dev.php/en`

Should i repeat `/{_locale}` in all route pattern because placeholder in prefix are not supported ? Sounds dirty :S

Comment: You could probably add a route with prefix '/' and then redirect to the front_homepage controller?

Comment: Yes, but i would have to repeat the `/{_locale}` prefix for all routes in VWFrontBundle.

Comment: Well, create a separate routing file (separate resource) for the '/' prefix, then you can use ``/{_locale}`` prefix for the VWFrontBundle.

Comment: I do not understand who it could resolve the problem :s

Comment: I think your problem is similar to one I had. Check the comment by @Crozin at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254152/locale-in-route-prefix